# dc.js: dealing with entries with multi-valued attributes

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am dealing with data that contain multi-valued attributes (e.g.: a company has branches distributed over three states).
When clicking the company with multiple branches, the geoChoroplethChart should highlight all the associated states.
But, this works currently only for the entry with single value(one state).
How could one realize the above-mentioned functionality?

```
var data= [
    {"Company":"MountainA","State":"CA PA NY"},
    {"Company":"HighlandA","State":"PA"}];
```

I modified the csv data for US Venture Capital Landscape 2011 and added multiple states for most of the entries.
E.g.: instead of single state ("CA"), now the state information includes multiple states such as "CA PA NY" (space-separated).
https://jsfiddle.net/woodlan/1ou8r1q9/1/

I guess one needs to modify this function?

```
var states = data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["State"];
  });
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [community fork of crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/), available in npm as crossfilter2, has a new feature in version 1.4 supporting array (tag) keys:

```
var states = data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["State"].split(' ');
  }, true // enable array keys
);
```

This will cause those rows to count once for each key which the dimension key function returns.

Crossfilter documentation - [Dimensions with Arrays](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays).

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon! You are always very helpful! It works now.
I have also realized that there are two repos:
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/releases
https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/releases
The latter one is what I need (crossfilter1.4) and it is called crossfilter2  in npm.

Comment: That's a good point, I've edited my answer to mention the fork. Glad it works for you. Disclosure: I'm a maintainer of this fork, but I did not develop this feature.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question: how could one best get the clicked items in javascript? (I tried a very hacky way...)
 (for current filter:CA, PA, one gets var selected_items= ['CA','PA'];)

Comment: [chart.filters()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filters)?

Comment: I used `usChart.filterHandler(function(dimension, filter){
              console.log(filter)
            });`, and got  ["CA", "PA"]. Somehow, quite hacky...

Comment: Naw, you shouldn't do that, that's for changing how the filters work (guess there's no harm though). If you're looking for a callback when the filters change, use `.on('filtered',...)`. If you just want to read the filters, `chart.filters()` as I linked above.

Comment: I would like to get the selected items as an array each time I click a state. These changes per click are typically shown in the html content ('Current filter: ').
I tried `.on('filtered', function(chart, filter){console.log(chart,filter)})`, but it did not print anything. What did I do wrong?
And for reading the filters with `chart.filters()`, how could one combine it with click event?
( `.on("click",...)` does not work and `geoChart.onClick =` seems to overwrite the default behavior.).

Comment: This is way beyond what comments were intended for, and had nothing to do with the current question. Thought it should work as I described, if it does not, please ask another question. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I will do it later. Thanks, Gordon.

Comment: Many thanks, Gordon. I found the issues. It works as you have described. (Sorry about the long comments here.)